# The square of an integer cannot be of the form $3k +2$, where $k$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the following Theorem:

The square of an integer cannot be of the form $3k +2$, where $k$ is an integer.

The following is my proof.

---

The square of an integer cannot be of the form $3k +2$, where $k$ is an integer.

*Proof.* Suppose on the contrary, a square of an integer can be of the form $3k +2$. It follows that there exists an integer $n$ such that

\begin{equation}
n^2 = 3k +2 \text{ for some integer $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{equation}

Making $k$ as the subject, one obtains

\begin{equation}
k = \frac{n^2 - 2}{3} \text{ for some integer $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{equation}

Because $(n^2 - 2) = (n -\sqrt{2})(n + \sqrt{2})$, the above equation can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
k = \frac{(n -\sqrt{2})(n + \sqrt{2})}{3} \text{ for some integer $k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{equation}

Since $3$ is a prime number, it follows that $3\mid (n -\sqrt{2})$ or $3 \mid(n + \sqrt{2})$.

However, $3\nmid \pm \sqrt{2}$, it follows that $3\nmid (n -\sqrt{2})$ and $3\nmid(n + \sqrt{2})$.

Therefore, one obtains a contradiction to the assumption that the square of an integer can be of the form $3k+2$.

---

Is the proof correct?

---

**Reference**

Daepp, U. and Gorkin, P., 2011. *Reading, Writing, and Proving*. 2nd ed. pp.55.

Comment: Why so complicated ? Just look at the expressions $(3n)^2=9n^2$ , $(3n+1)^2=9n^2+6n+1$ , $(3n+2)^2=9n^2+12n+4$ modulo $3$

Comment: How should I understand if the integer is the factor of the irrational number?

Comment: Another flaw is that we have $3\mid n-\sqrt{2}$ OR $3\mid n+\sqrt{2}$. This would not imply $3\mid \sqrt{2}$ , even if this would make sense. Only if both divisibilities would hold, we could conclude the claimed divisibility.

Comment: Your logic would also say that since $3\not\mid\pm\sqrt7$, there is no square of the form $3k+7$. But $16=3\cdot3+7$ is a square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof doesn't make sense to me, because you're applying Euclid's Lemma to irrationals, when it only holds for integers.

A much simpler proof is just to exhaust the squares modulo 3:

$$(3k)^2\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
$$(3k\pm 1)^2=9k^2\pm 6k+1\equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

None are of the form $2\pmod 3$, so it is impossible to have a square of that form.

Answer (score 1):

How do you understand when the integer is the factor of the irrational number?

---

You can construct the proof as follows:

We have,

$$3k+2 \equiv 2~(\text{mod}~ 3)$$

Then, let $n=3k-m, ~ 0≤m≤2$, we get

$$\begin{align}n^2&=9k^2-6mk+m^2\\
&=3(3k^2-2mk)+m^2\end{align}$$

where, $m^2\in\left\{0,1,4\right\}.$

Finally, observe that:

$$n^2\equiv m^2 \not\equiv 2~(\text{mod}~ 3).$$

Comment: We have to take $4$ modulo $3$, but apart from that the answer is OK (+1)

Comment: @Peter thank you very much. Please let me ask.. I think I have a flaw, but I'm missing it. Can you please help/elaborate a little more? I could bot understand 4 modulo 3 part..

Comment: You reduced the problem to the problem whether $m^2\equiv 2\mod 3$ is possible for some $m$ in the range $[0,2]$. This is a valid approach. The squares are $0,1,4$ , modulo $3$ $0,1,1$ , so $2$ does not occur.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for explanation! I edited my answer.

Comment: Please, leave a little comment if I still have an error.  Thank you for review my answer @Peter .